# Recursive Triggering between two objects

Tags: apex, trigger

I have Object Alpha and Object Num with fields A,B,C and 1,2,3 respectively. 
I have to write trigger on both objects

- when field A on Object Alpha is updated, field 1 on Object Num should be updated and vise versa.
- Similarly when field B on Object Alpha is update, field 2 on Object Num should be updated and vise versa.
- Similarly when field c on Object Alpha is updated, field 1 on Object Num should be updated and vise versa.

How to should avoid recursive triggering (when field A updates field 1 then trigger on Object Num is not triggered to update field A on Object Alpha that again triggers a field update .... ) Any inputs?

Comment: Are object alpha and object num related?  What is the relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion guards are very tricky. Using a simple static Boolean is a *bad* practice: there are lots of reasons for your trigger to be fired more than once in a transaction, and using a `runOnce`-style Boolean will mean your trigger just silently does nothing in those cases. This often produces difficult to debug behavior.

Instead, use static Booleans that are scoped to a single DML statement, like this.

```
class TriggerContext {
    static Boolean isUpdatingOtherObject = false;
}

trigger SomeTrigger on Object_A__c (after update) {
    if (!TriggerContext.isUpdatingOtherObject) {
        TriggerContext.isUpdatingOtherObject = true;
        update [SELECT Id FROM Object_B__c ...];
        TriggerContext.isUpdatingOtherObject = false;
    }
}

trigger AnotherTrigger on Object_B__c (after update) {
    if (!TriggerContext.isUpdatingOtherObject) {
        TriggerContext.isUpdatingOtherObject = true;
        update [SELECT Id FROM Object_A__c ...];
        TriggerContext.isUpdatingOtherObject = false;
    }
}
```

Note that the recursion guard is active *only* during the DML operation against the other object in the pair. This ensures that both triggers fire exactly when they need to, but don't fire in response to one another's updates.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a helper like this

```
public class ContactTriggerHelper {public static Boolean runOnce = true;
                                   public static void onAfterUpdate(List<Contact> newacc){
         for(Integer i=0;i<newacc.size();i++)
         {
       insert (new Account(Name='Test'+i));
        runOnce = true;
        System.debug('Is After Update');
         }}

}
```

and then in trigger you can check

```
  if(Trigger.isAfter  && ContactTriggerHelper.runOnce){
         ContactTriggerHelper.runOnce = false;
        ContactTriggerHelper.onAfterUpdate(Trigger.New);
    }
```

create same for other objects too

Comment: Could the down voter please explain why they downvoted this answer so people know why it is not a good one?